# Is the system's "KnownDLLs" list of dependency walker hard-coded?

Tags: dll

When opening the Module Search Order dialog of Dependency Walker (depends.exe), the list of the system well-known DLLs does NOT fit with the one that is located in the registry under the following key "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\session manager\knowndlls".

Is the list hardcoded in Dependency Walker?

Answer (score 0):

1. [*Known DLLs* is a caching system for Windows NT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/07/19/187752.aspx)
2. [*Dependency Walker* builds a tree of the dependencies of each DLL](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

A list is hard-coded in *Known DLLs* and then it is extended based on the DLLs' static dependencies while the *Dependency Walker* application scans any DLL for any dependencies (from its homepage: "Dependency Walker handles all types of module dependencies, including implicit, explicit (dynamic / runtime), forwarded, delay-loaded, and injected").

Use *Dependency Walker* if you want to reliably find a DLLs dependencies instead of the NT registry.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the "Know DLLs" registry enumerates the list of System known Libraries. The point is that depends seems to have its own hard-code list of this enumeration. 

Using depends does to analyze an image file does not extent this list at all. This list is system dependant.

Comment: Actually, the DLLs dependencies found by dependency walker are not a replacement of some NT Registry! Dependency walker and similar tools scan image dependencies AND the Registry to determine the search order of dependencies.